# Tkinter pack_forget() and pack() issue on key-release event

Tags: python, tkinter

**My Requirement** 
I am developing a program in which I handle space and KeyPress-space Events to handle time based event.

What I am doing is that on the start of program a window gets open to display a time interval, say "5" which depicts 5 Second. Once the time lapses(5Sec) the text "5" gets disappear.

After that the user is required to press **space** key, when user press **space** key the same number will display until user don't release **space** key.

I have given 2 second gap to show next interval(once user releases the **space**) and in that interval the number should not appear which was appearing in previous set time interval **space** Event.

**Problem Statement:**
The issue that I am facing is that I have managed to display number(text) on key press but when I key-release, time interval is not disappearing for 2 second.

Here is my Code:

```
from tkinter import Label, Tk
import time

times = [3, 4, 5]
loop = 0

class Demo:
    def __init__(self, master):
        global times, loop
        self.parent = master
        self.lbl = Label(master, text=times[loop])
        master.after(times[loop]*1000, self.hideLabelAfterSomeTime)
        master.bind("<space>", self.hideLabel)
        master.bind("<KeyRelease-space>", self.showLabel)
        print('called', loop)
        self.lbl.pack()

    def hideLabel(self, event):
        global loop, times
        self.lbl.config(text=times[loop])
        self.lbl.pack()

    def showLabel(self, event):
        global loop
        self.lbl.pack_forget()
        time.sleep(2)
        loop += 1
        Demo(self.parent)

    def hideLabelAfterSomeTime(self):
        self.lbl.config(text= '')

master = Tk()
app = Demo(master)
master.geometry("400x300+400+200")
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is very unclear what this thing should do... so it is not easy to help you fix it... It also throws an error after a few clicks on the canvas: `list index out of range`......... Maybe you want to clarify the states your system passes through, and maybe your mistake will appear when you do that. :)

Comment: While user press <space> key a box should be appear and when user leaves <space> the box should be disappear and next event should be occur and again same operation should repeat until the loop is finished. Please ignore out off index error for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go..Please let me know if you have any further query -

```
from tkinter import Label, Tk
import time

times = [3, 4, 5]
loop = 0

class Demo:
    def __init__(self, master):
        global times, loop
        self.parent = master
        self.lbl = Label(master, text=times[loop])
        master.after(times[loop]*1000, self.hideLabelAfterSomeTime)
        master.bind("<space>", self.hideLabel)

    master.bind("<KeyRelease-space>", self.showLabel)
    print('called', loop)
    self.lbl.pack()

def hideLabel(self, event):
    global loop, times
    self.lbl.config(text=times[loop])
    self.lbl.pack()

def showLabel(self, event):

    global loop
    self.lbl.pack_forget() 
    self.parent.update()
    time.sleep(2)
    loop += 1
    Demo(self.parent)

def hideLabelAfterSomeTime(self):
    self.lbl.config(text= '')

master = Tk()
app = Demo(master)
master.geometry("400x300+400+200")
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. It actually resolved my problem. Appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have found a "crevice" in the way Python interacts with the Tk main loop. At least on my system (Python 2.7, Fedora 22, x86_64) none of the operations in *showLabel()* have any effect on the screen until the function (including *time.sleep(2))* completes.

If you modify the code as follows for troubleshooting, I think you can see what I mean.

```
def hideLabel(self, event):
    global loop, times
#       self.lbl.config(text=times[loop])
    self.lbl.config(bg = "red")
    self.lbl.pack()

def showLabel(self, event):
    global loop
#       self.lbl.pack_forget()
    self.lbl.config(fg = "blue")
    time.sleep(2)
    loop += 1
    Demo(self.parent)

def hideLabelAfterSomeTime(self):
#       self.lbl.config(text= '')
    self.lbl.config(bg = "green")
```

The second label now shows up below the first. The first label gets a blue foreground, but not on the keypress, as we would expect. It apparently only gets it when the function returns, after *time.sleep()*.

I don't pretend to completely understand this - someone who has a deep understanding of Python and Tk might explain. One workaround for this particular program is to add *update_idletasks()*. This (warning: sloppy terminology ahead) forces the Tk main loop to immediately process pending events.

```
def showLabel(self, event):
    global loop
#   self.lbl.pack_forget()
    self.lbl.config(fg = "blue")
    master.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(2)
    loop += 1
    Demo(self.parent)
```

On my system, that made the first label turn blue before time.sleep(). I didn't experiment beyond that.
p.s showLabel() hides the label and hideLabel() shows it?

EDIT: The following slight mod of the original posted code works on my system almost as I would expect. I'm not 100% sure what it is intended to do. But the current label does disappear when I tap the space bar, and the next one shows up 2 seconds later, only to be blanked a variable time after that.

The only puzzle I ran into was that my system basically went crazy when I tried to hold down the space bar for more than 2 seconds. It turned out that the key auto-repeat was kicking in on my system, giving me dozens of keystrokes and causing dozens of subscript out-of-range errors. I gave up at that point so I still don't know how the program behaves if given a single space-down followed 3 seconds later by a single space-up.

```
from Tkinter import Label, Tk
import time

times = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
loop = 0

class Demo:
    def __init__(self, master):
        global times, loop
        self.parent = master
        self.lbl = Label(master, text=times[loop])
        master.after(times[loop]*1000, self.hideLabelAfterSomeTime)
        master.bind("<space>", self.hideLabel)
        master.bind("<KeyRelease-space>", self.showLabel)
        master.bind("<h>", self.showLabel)
        print('called', loop)
        self.lbl.pack()
        for child in master.children: print child

    def hideLabel(self, event):
        global loop, times
        self.lbl.config(text=times[loop])
        self.lbl.pack()

    def showLabel(self, event):
        global loop
        self.lbl.pack_forget()
        master.update_idletasks()
        time.sleep(2)
        loop += 1
        Demo(self.parent)

    def hideLabelAfterSomeTime(self):
        self.lbl.config(text= '')
        self.lbl.config(bg = "green")

master = Tk()
app = Demo(master)
master.geometry("400x300+400+200")
master.mainloop()
```

If the pack_forget has no effect on your system even with the update_idletasks(), I'd have to guess that the Tk main loop is more platform dependent than is widely known.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I'll try to take another look Tuesday night (GMT -6).

Comment: Seems to work more or less as expected on my system. There may be some differences between platforms - dunno. Hmm. I just now re-read your explanation after first comment of what you want to see. It will never work that way on my system unless / until I disable key auto-repeat. Sorry - no easy way for me to test it.

Comment: ok, thanks for you kind reply. If you have any solution regard this problem please ping me